# Simpy Request Specific Resource

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, simpy

I have a Resource with capacity=2 and both slots have an initial value as attributes. Let's say the initial value is set to 1 for both slots. Now processes request the resource, and the processes can have a value of 1, 2, 3 or 4. This process value is also something like an attribute. Now what I want to simulate is that when a process requests the resource, it first compares it's own value with the value of the 2 slots. It prioritizes the slot with same value. If none of the slots have the same value, it chooses at random. After the process releases the slot, the slot's value is changed to be equal to the process value. 
My idea was to use a FilterStore and put the Resource as items into the store. But how do I set an attribute to the items and how do I change does attributes as described above?
I hope I described my problem crearly. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a little code that I used for my problem. I initialy defined my resources in a class, but then changed that and put the resources directly into the FilterStore.

```
import simpy

#class Pre_Assem:
#    def __init__(self, env, name, value):
#        self.nodes = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1) 
#        self.name = name
#        self.value = value

class Job:
    def __init__(self, env, name, release, value):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.release = release
        self.value = value


def Process(env, job, pre_assem):
    print('initial slot values: ', pre_assem.items)
    yield env.timeout(job.release)

    print('available slots before: ', pre_assem.capacity)
    request = yield pre_assem.get(lambda request: request['value'] == job.value) | pre_assem.get()
    print('available slots after: ', pre_assem.capacity)
    print('slot requested: ' , request)        

    print('slot is beeing used')
    yield env.timeout(10)
    print('slots after use: ', pre_assem.items)
    yield pre_assem.put({'value': job.value})
    print('new slots values: ', pre_assem.items)




env = simpy.Environment()
pre_assem = simpy.FilterStore(env, 2)

#preassem1 = Pre_Assem(env, 1, 1)
#preassem2 = Pre_Assem(env, 2, 1)
#pre_assem.items = [preassem1, preassem2]

pre_assem.put({'name':1, 'value':1})
pre_assem.put({'name':2, 'value':1})

jobs = [Job(env, 1, 0, 1),
        Job(env, 2, 0, 2), 
        Job(env, 3, 60, 3)]

for job in jobs:
    env.process(Process(env, job, pre_assem))
env.run()
```

It works, but doesn't do excatly what I want it to.